# Should I use redirect_to :back or request.refferer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to redirect a user back to the previous page they were on (the refferer), should I use `redirect_to :back` or use the following block of code:

```
session[:return_to] = request.referer
# Do whatever you want
redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
```

Are there any advantages to the longer method, or should I switch to the quick way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 4, `redirect_to :back` is the same as `redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])`.  And `request` is an instance of ActionDispatch::Request which inherits from Rack::Request which defines `referer` as:

```
def referer
  @env['HTTP_REFERER']
end
alias referrer referer
```

So, it doesn't look like it matters all that much which you use.  I would be inclined to use :back myself.

Comment: Thanks, using :back would also result in a cleaner code, so I think I'll switch!

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect_to :back
```

is a shorthand for

```
redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])
```

so, your longer method is different, so the choice is up to you (i would use :back, you are storing something on session and then deleting that something, that's extra work)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
redirect_to request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to (pre Rails 3) or http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to (Rails 3)